What game are these pieces from?
These pieces are at least 20 years old, probably older.  I remember examining them and liking them when I was a kid and asking my mom what they were for, and she wasn't sure.  I just came across them again and decided in this age of the internet, perhaps someone can help me identify them.  :)
Quarter is included for scale.  The silvery triangles on the large black disks appear only on one side as shown; the other side is plain black.  None of the other pieces have any patterns or shapes on them.

Since my grandma had board games going back at least to the fifties, it's also possible these pieces are quite a bit older than me, but I first saw them sometime roughly in the range 1996–2001.  I can't swear they are all from the same game but the smooth plastic material does feel consistent between them.  Heck, I can't even swear they are game pieces but I don't know what else they could be.
Anyone recognize them?

Have you tried to google search by image?

@Cohensius I hadn't, but I just tried it without much luck.
